# An example which we can't use for Bounded Convergence Theorem and L.D.C.T

Tags: measure-theory

Let consider the following example
$$f_n=\frac{1}{n} \chi_{[1,n]} \text{ on} [1.\infty)$$

can't we use this example for the Bounded Convergence Theorem and Lebesgue dominated Convergence theorems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f_n \leq f$ then $f(x) \geq \frac  1n$ on $(n,n+1)$ so $\int f(x) dx \geq \sum_n \frac 1 n =\infty$. So there is no dominating integrable function.